# How to correctly use ng-View with md-tabs in AngularJS and Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use Angular Material md-tabs in a web site where each tabs represents a different url determined using an ng-view tag. The web site is here: [here](http://franklyscarletgallery.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/). Visually it works but I'm noticing the pages get loaded 5 times every time I change the tab .... once for each tab location.

Is there a setting or something I need to change to do this correctly?

The code for the tabs is as follow:

```
       <div class="tabsdemoDynamicHeight">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="selectedIndex">
                <md-tab label="Featured">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="Art For Sale">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="Philosophy">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="Policies">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>
                <md-tab label="Contact Us">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">
                        <div ng-view></div>
                    </md-content>
                </md-tab>  
            </md-tabs>
        </md-content>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still interested in this: you need to use `md-on-select` directive to call a function in the controller to redirect to another url understood by your $routeProvider, for instance:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController as vm" layout="column">
:
<md-content flex>
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-stretch-tabs="always">
    <md-tab md-on-select="vm.tabDashboard()">
      <md-tab-label>
        <md-icon>dashboard</md-icon>&nbsp;Dashboard
      </md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab md-on-select="vm.tabReports()">
      <md-tab-label>
        <md-icon>trending_up</md-icon>&nbsp;Reports
      </md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab md-on-select="vm.tabManageEmployee()">
      <md-tab-label>
        <md-icon>people</md-icon>&nbsp;Manage Employee
      </md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
     :
     :
  </md-tabs>
  <div ng-view></div>
</md-content>
:
</body>
```

and in your appController do something like this:

```
(function () {
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'md.data.table'])
    .controller('appController', appController)
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl: '/views/dashboard.html'
            })
            .when('/reports', {
                templateUrl: '/views/reports.html'
            })
            .when('/manageEmployee', {
                templateUrl: '/views/manageEmployee.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                templateUrl: '/views/otherwise.html'
            });
    });

function appController($mdMedia, $scope, $http, session, $location) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.tabDashboard = function () {
        $location.path('/dashboard');
    };
    vm.tabReports = function () { 
        $location.path('/reports');
    };
    vm.tabManageEmployee = function () { 
        $location.path('/manageEmployee');
    };
}
})();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have more than one `ng-view` per page. If you need to include different HTML files you should use `ng-include`.

`<div ng-include="'template.html'">`

Note the inner apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Ng-view will refresh every time you change the current route. Also see the [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) documentation.
You can avoid this by creating custom directives for each tab who will load the needed template once you click on the corresponding tab.

ngView is used as the highest level of view in your DOM and is particularly using once. When you need to load different tabs, it is adviced to use directives. Documentation about directives you can find [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).