# Convert AngularJS Material <md-tabs> + AngularJS ng-include into ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

Using AngularJS material's  and AngularJS' ng-include works fine but when the file gets huge the page slows. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883546/how-to-correctly-use-ng-view-with-md-tabs-in-angularjs-and-angular-material) uses ng-View but [Itamar L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5165628/itamar-l) suggested to use ng-include. Is there a way to convert it to ngRoute like what [abr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5188626/abr) suggested. I'm kind of new to AngularJS and I gladly appreciate any help.:)

I have created a prototype on [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/9ggKN9gv6ZnmbqTXNgYw/). Please check it out.

**EDITED:**

What I did was this,

```
<md-content>
    <md-tabs md-align-tabs="bottom" md-swipe-content="true" md-dynamic-height="true" md-border-bottom="" >
      <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" label="{{ tab.title }}">
        <md-tab-label>
          <img ng-src="{{ tab.thumbnail }}">
        </md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
            <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
```

and the script looks like this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

      $scope.tabs = [
          { title:'Page 1', content:'page1.html', thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/2vl2MCk.png' },
          { title:'Page 1', content:'page2.html', thumbnail: 'http://i.imgur.com/GueewHO.png' }
      ];
});
```

Is there a way to modify the script instead of using ng-include?
Just like what [abr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5188626/abr) suggested.
Thank you.

Comment: Please include your code snippits here.  Any linked code could go missing and then your question is difficult to understand

Comment: hi brody, thanks for the quick reply.Here it is [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9ggKN9gv6ZnmbqTXNgYw?p=preview)

Comment: @Eunil, Brody is asking you to include your snippets _in your question_, not as links.

Comment: hi, brody, I'm sorry, I've updated my question. @SimonMᶜKenzie, thank you.